# From Java/C++ to XML

Tags: java, c++, xml

I know Java and C++ but am looking to get in to XML. I don't want to waste time reading over the basics of programming in a book, so has anyone any recommendations for resources for learning XML that assume a knowledge of programming already, or even better highlight how to switch from Java/C++ to XML ie. main differences etcs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is not a programming language. It is a markup language. It's mainly used to store/transmit data in a structured manner.

If you know Java and C++, there are libraries out there that can load and parse XML files.

Adding to Soto's answer, you can technically use it to describe behavior (e.g. XAML, processing instructions), but most of the time it's for storing and transmitting data in a certain way.

In your case, XML can be used to describe the GUI layout of an Android application.

Answer (score 2):

XML is not a programming language as Java/C++, as it cannot describe behavior.

XML is a markup language specification used to describe data.

Comment: So you have tags in it but the real reason I want to know is I understand Android Apps are built in XML and Java so was wondering how you would go about this

Comment: I think you use XML to describe the UI in Android apps, not to program them. Not sure about this thought, I haven't developed for Android.

Comment: I will look into it over the summer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from the others any decent XML reference will get you started, try here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To get to the core, you can go to the source and [read the overview](http://www.w3.org/XML/) or go directly to the [XML 1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/).

Answer (score 0):

XML is a Extensive Markup language, Since you are from java or C++ background, XML will be a topup for you in your skillset

For Java, you can JAXP for DOM parsing and SAX parsing an XML File.

Personnally i dont think that you will get into completely XML platform, I feel its just extra ad on along with your main skill.